# Hugo Error: no existing content directory configured for this project

Tags: go, hugo

I'm getting this error when I try to create a new content in my hugo server on Ubuntu.
I have a hugo.toml config file with this content:

```
baseURL = 'https://mytraveltreasury/'
languageCode = 'en-us'
title = 'My Travel Treasury'
theme = 'ananke'


[params]
  commentoEnable = true
  
[languages]
  [languages.en]
    title = "My Travel Treasury"
    weight = 1
    contentDir = "content/en"
    # languageDirection = 'rtl' for Right-To-Left languages
  [languages.it]
    title = "My Travel Treasury IT"
    weight = 2
    contentDir = "content/it"
  [languages.es]
    title = "My Travel Treasury ES"
    weight = 3
    contentDir = "content/es"    
[[params.ananke_socials]]
name = "twitter"
url = "https://twitter.com/GoHugoIO"
```

and I created an additional config.toml in the root directory with just one single line:

```
contentDir = "content"
```

In my root directory I have a folder called content and I created manually a new file colled index.md.

I have booted my hugo server with hugo server and Ctl+c and tried to create a new file for my blog content with this command hugo new content content/first.md, but I got this error: Error: no existing content directory configured for this project

Any ideas for fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned, there's no need to configure an additional file and configuration should be defined on hugo.toml.

The issue was as described in the question that I was defining several contentDir for the addtional languages. That was causing the system to not be able to define where and raising the error that contentDis wasn't defined.

I removed the three locations and added the one from my config.toml, removed config.toml and reboot the server.

And voila!, it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

The config file should be called `hugo.toml` not `config.toml`. See the documentation [here](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/).
Either rename it, or run `hugo` using the `--config` parameter:
`hugo --config config.toml`

Other parts of Hugo *are* configured using `config.toml`, such as inside themes, which might be where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. No need for additional configuration files.